# gsutil copy returning "AccessDeniedException: 403 Insufficient Permission" from GCE

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am logged in to a GCE instance via SSH. From there I would like to access the Storage with the help of a Service Account:

```
GCE> gcloud auth list
Credentialed accounts:
 - 1234567890-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com (active)
```

I first made sure that this Service account is flagged "Can edit" in the permissions of the project I am working in. I also made sure to give him the Write ACL on the bucket I would like him to copy a file:

```
local> gsutil acl ch -u 1234567890-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com:W gs://mybucket
```

But then the following command fails:

```
GCE> gsutil cp test.txt gs://mybucket/logs
```

(I also made sure that "logs" is created under "mybucket").

The error message I get is:

```
Copying file://test.txt [Content-Type=text/plain]...
AccessDeniedException: 403 Insufficient Permission               0 B
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Was the GCE VM created with full control or read/write GCS scope?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I was not aware of that option indeed. I re-created the instance with the option enabled and it worked. If you could suggest to turn on the flag as an answer I would happily flag it.

Answer (score 193, accepted):

One other thing to look for is to make sure you set up the appropriate scopes when creating the GCE VM. Even if a VM has a service account attached, it must be assigned devstorage scopes in order to access GCS.

For example, if you had created your VM with `devstorage.read_only` scope, trying to write to a bucket would fail, even if your service account has permission to write to the bucket. You would need `devstorage.full_control` or `devstorage.read_write`.

See the section on [Preparing an instance to use service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/authentication#using) for details.

Note: the default compute service account has very limited scopes (including having read-only to GCS). This is done because the default service account has Project Editor IAM permissions. If you use any user service account this is not typically a problem since user created service accounts get all scope access by default.

After adding necessary scopes to the VM, `gsutil` may still be using cached credentials which don't have the new scopes. Delete `~/.gsutil` before trying the gsutil commands again. (Thanks to [@mndrix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/174463) for pointing this out in the comments.)

Comment: As of now, you can edit the scopes. Stop the machine - edit - then change the Cloud API access scopes. I believe this has only be available for about a month now.

Answer (score 67):

You have to log in with an account that has the permissions you need for that project:

```
gcloud auth login
```

Comment: Do not forget to issue `gcloud auth revoke <email-account>` after you are finished.

Answer (score 56):

`gsutil config -b`

Then surf to the URL it provides,
**[ CLICK Allow ]**

Then copy the verification code and paste to terminal.

Comment: Note this doesn’t work if you run `gsutil` from `ssh`.

Comment: It "doesn't work" in so far as not opening your browser.  Instead, it provides a url for you to manually copy and paste.

Comment: This also works fine for everyone else _if you drop the `-b`_. That will not open a browser, but will simply spit out a url that can be opened outside of the shell.

Comment: Nice - This is the first solution I have found which does not require restarting the VM (and thereby potentially losing data).

Comment: This solution worked for me without restart. Thank you!!

Answer (score 35):

1. Stop VM
2. goto --> VM instance details.
3. in "Cloud API access scopes" select "Allow full access to all Cloud APIs" then
   Click "save".
4. restart VM and Delete ~/.gsutil .

Comment: You need to stop the instance before editing any permissions

Comment: Thank you, this one worked perfectly for me on 2 Feb 2022. Looks like the best up to date answer.

Comment: Excellent, worked in May 2022

Answer (score 14):

*I have written an answer to this question since I can not post comments:*

This error can also occur if you're running the `gsutil` command with a `sudo` prefix in some cases.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: I have given the answer (+1) so that @TheLoneDeranger will be closer in reputation to the 'Post comment' privilege.

Comment: this saved my life!

Answer (score 4):

1. After you have created the bucket, go to the permissions tab and add your email and set **Storage Admin** permission.

[image: screenshot]

2. Access VM instance via SSH >> run command: `gcloud auth login` and follow the steps.

Ref: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gce-discussion/0L6sLRjX8kg/kP47FklzBgAJ

Answer (score 3):

So I tried a bunch of things trying to copy from GCS bucket to my VM. 
Hope this post helps someone.

Via SSHed connection:
[image]

and following this script:

```
sudo gsutil cp gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/[OBJECT_NAME] [OBJECT_DESTINATION_IN_LOCAL]
```

Got this error:

> AccessDeniedException: 403 Access Not Configured. Please go to the Google Cloud Platform Console (https://cloud.google.com/console#/project) for your project, select APIs and Auth and enable the Google Cloud Storage JSON API.

What fixed this was following "Activating the API" section mentioned in this link -
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/

[image]

Once I activated the API then I authenticated myself in SSHed window via

```
gcloud auth login
```

Following authentication procedure I was finally able to download from Google Storage Bucket to my VM.

**PS**

I did make sure to:

1. Make sure that gsutils are installed on my VM instance.
2. Go to my bucket, go to the permissions tab and add desired service accounts and set Storage Admin permission / role.
   [image]

   3.Make sure my VM had proper Cloud API access scopes:
   [image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

From the docs: 
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances#changeserviceaccountandscopes

You need to first stop the instance -> go to edit page -> go to "Cloud API access scopes" and choose "storage full access or read/write or whatever you need it for"

> Changing the service account and access scopes for an instance If you
>   want to run the VM as a different identity, or you determine that the
>   instance needs a different set of scopes to call the required APIs,
>   you can change the service account and the access scopes of an
>   existing instance. For example, you can change access scopes to grant
>   access to a new API, or change an instance so that it runs as a
>   service account that you created, instead of the Compute Engine
>   Default Service Account.
>
> To change an instance's service account and access scopes, the
>   instance must be temporarily stopped. To stop your instance, read the
>   documentation for Stopping an instance. After changing the service
>   account or access scopes, remember to restart the instance. Use one of
>   the following methods to the change service account or access scopes
>   of the stopped instance.

Comment: Still valid in 2021

Answer (score -11):

Change the permissions of bucket.

Add a user for "All User" and give "Storage Admin" access.

[image]

Comment: This will give write access to everybody to the bucket. Pretty sure you don't want to do that :)