# Firestore client in python (as user) using firebase_admin or google.cloud.firestore

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-authentication, firebase-admin

I am building a python client-side application that uses Firestore. I have successfully used Google Identity Platform to sign up and sign in to the Firebase project, and created a working Firestore client using google.cloud.firestore.Client which is authenticated as a user:

```py
import json
import requests
import google.oauth2.credentials
from google.cloud import firestore

request_url = f"https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key={self.__api_key}"
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"}
data = json.dumps({"email": self.__email, "password": self.__password, "returnSecureToken": True})
response = requests.post(request_url, headers=headers, data=data)
try:
    response.raise_for_status()
except (HTTPError, Exception):
    content = response.json()
    error = f"error: {content['error']['message']}"
    raise AuthError(error)

json_response = response.json()
self.__token = json_response["idToken"]
self.__refresh_token = json_response["refreshToken"]

credentials = google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials(self.__token,
                                                    self.__refresh_token,
                                                    client_id="",
                                                    client_secret="",
                                                    token_uri=f"https://securetoken.googleapis.com/v1/token?key={self.__api_key}"
                                                    )

self.__db = firestore.Client(self.__project_id, credentials)
```

I have the problem, however, that when the token has expired, I get the following error:

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 57, in error_remapped_callable
    return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 826, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 729, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _InactiveRpcError(state)
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.UNAUTHENTICATED
    details = "Missing or invalid authentication."
    debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1613043524.699081937","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:172.217.16.74:443","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1055,"grpc_message":"Missing or invalid authentication.","grpc_status":16}"
>

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/home/my_app/src/controllers/im_alive.py", line 20, in run
    self.__device_api.set_last_updated(utils.device_id())
  File "/home/my_app/src/api/firestore/firestore_device_api.py", line 21, in set_last_updated
    "lastUpdatedTime": self.__firestore.SERVER_TIMESTAMP
  File "/home/my_app/src/api/firestore/firestore.py", line 100, in update
    ref.update(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/document.py", line 382, in update
    write_results = batch.commit()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/batch.py", line 147, in commit
    metadata=self._client._rpc_metadata,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/gapic/firestore_client.py", line 1121, in commit
    request, retry=retry, timeout=timeout, metadata=metadata
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py", line 145, in __call__
    return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 286, in retry_wrapped_func
    on_error=on_error,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 184, in retry_target
    return target()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/api_core/timeout.py", line 214, in func_with_timeout
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 59, in error_remapped_callable
    six.raise_from(exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc), exc)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
google.api_core.exceptions.Unauthenticated: 401 Missing or invalid authentication.
```

I have tried omitting the token and only specifying the refresh token, and then calling `credentials.refresh()`, but the `expires_in` in the response from the `https://securetoken.googleapis.com/v1/token` endpoint is a string instead of a number ([docs here](https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/reference/securetoken/rest/v1/token)), which makes `_parse_expiry(response_data)` in `google.oauth2._client.py:257` raise an exception.

Is there any way to use the `firestore.Client` from either `google.cloud` or `firebase_admin` and have it automatically handle refreshing tokens, or do I need to switch to the manually calling the Firestore RPC API and refreshing tokens at the correct time?

Note: There are no users interacting with the python app, so the solution must not require user interaction.

Comment: I'm still learning about some stuff on Google Cloud but in imho if you expect to work without user interaction then you should use a service account as client authentication. Those are treated differently i believe, and should have some tweak about the token expiration handled by the IAM

Comment: If there is a way for a service account to be treated exactly like a normal Firebase user, then this is definitely a possiblity. However, I have not seen anything like that

Comment: That sounds super intersting to me as well! I see you used some class for it. Do you think you could wrap this in a pipy package something like firestore-cloud-client ? and do something smiliar as in the older firestore python API? Would be really helpful!

Comment: The class is mainly there for other reasons, but there isn't much to it. The only addition to the above code to make it work is:
`from google.oauth2 import _client`
`_client._parse_expiry = parse_expiry`
Where `parse_expiry` is a function that just casts `expires_in` from the response to an int before calculating the datetime:
`expires_in = response_data.get("expires_in", None)`
`return datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=int(expires_in)) if expires_in else None`

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just pass the string cast as integer `_parse_expiry(int(float(response_data)))` ?

If it is not working you could try to make a call and refresh token after getting and error 401, see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66216203/whats-the-right-way-to-use-tokens-for-rest-apis/) for the general idea on how to handle tokens.

Comment: That is actually my temporary hack. Because _parse_expiry is inside the Google Oauth2 library, I have to overwrite the function as follows: `from google.oauth2 import _client`


`_client._parse_expiry = my_parse_expiry`. Can you explain why you are casting the value to a `float` first?

Comment: I was not sure what would be the response.data. if there is no decimal you can just ignore it and only cast to int.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Marco, it is recommended that you use a [service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts) if it's going to be used in an environment without user. When you use service account, you can just set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable to location of service account json file and just instantiate the firestore Client without any credentials (The credentials will be picked up automatically):

```py
import firestore
client = firestore.Client()
```

and run it as (assuming Linux):

```sh
$ export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/credentials.json
$ python file.py
```

Still, if you really want to use user credentials for the script, you can install the [Google Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk), then:

```
$ gcloud auth application-default login
```

This will open browser and for you to select account and login. After logging in, it creates a "virtual" service account file corresponding to your user account (that will also be loaded automatically by clients). Here too, you don't need to pass any parameters to your client.

See also: [Difference between “gcloud auth application-default login” and “gcloud auth login”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53306131/difference-between-gcloud-auth-application-default-login-and-gcloud-auth-logi)

Comment: Is it possible to configure the service account to be treated as a regular Firebase user? I am not looking for a server-side solution, so it has to be possible to get a Firebase user ID, and the reads/writes from/to Firebase and Firestore must be checked against the security rules

Comment: What if I need to deploy this in a container and can't deploy a creds.json file into the container. How would I create the Client object?

Comment: Load in the creds from another source such as Google Secret Manager