# reading CSV file form Google Cloud storage using Python pandas locally

Tags: python, pandas, csv, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I am trying to read a CSV file in a Google Cloud bucket locally using Pandas.
I have logged in using `gcloud auth login` and have configured the project. However, when I try to read the CSV file using  `df = pd.read_csv(f"gs://mybucket/myfolder/mycsv.csv")` I get a 401 error:

```
Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object., 401
```

I was wondering what further steps should I take so I can directly read the csv file? I have checked the `gcloud config` and my account is listed there.

Comment: It's unclear but I suspect you need to authenticate. The best way to do this is to use Application Default Credentials. See: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#automatically

Comment: ... And you'll want to ensure the account has, at least `roles/storage.objectViewer` or `roles/storage.objectAdmin`. See: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#automatically

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the credentials established by [`gcloud auth login`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/login) will not be picked up by your code. Please, see [this great SO question and related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53306131/difference-between-gcloud-auth-application-default-login-and-gcloud-auth-logi) for an in-deep explatation.

As suggested in the above-mentioned question, you can use [gcloud auth application-default login](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/login) instead.

As suggested in the [SDK documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#setting_up_authentication), you can set the value of the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable as well.

Finally, you can initialize your storage client by providing explicit credentials: please, see the relevant [documentation here](https://googleapis.dev/python/google-api-core/latest/auth.html); this documentation provides in addition a great summary of all the mentioned authentication options.