# 'Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object.' ERROR when calling a GCP API in maven project

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to read a file form google cloud storage using the following API, in a spring boot application:
`GET https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/bucket/o/object`
This is my code:

```
@Component("GetObjFromGCP")
class GetObjFromGCP{
    

    
    public void readFromFile() throws UnirestException{

        HttpResponse<String> jsonResponse 
          = Unirest.get("https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/sagessapp_test/o/apache%20camel%20notes.txt?alt=media")
          .header("accept", "application/json")
          .asString();

        System.out.println(jsonResponse.getBody());
    }
}
```

However I am getting this error:

```
Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object.
```

I have a json file containing the service account credentials and the appropriate role to read files from my bucket.
the application.properties file:
`spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location=classpath:/gcp-credentials.json`

So any idea how can I solve this error?
Thank you

Comment: I think this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70028077/13171940) might help you with your issue

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use one of Google's client libraries; these provide a higher-level abstraction **and** handle authentication too. See [Cloud Storage client libraries (Java)](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java)

If you do not want to use the client libraries, to use the low-level REST API directly, you will need to include an `Authorization` header. In the case of Google (Cloud Platform), the **easiest** way to acquire an access token is to use `gcloud` (see below):

(either) For testing using your own account credentials:

```sh
TOKEN=$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)
```

(or) To use the service account:

```sh
gcloud auth activate-service-account \
--key-file=/path/to/your/key.json

TOKEN=$(gcloud auth print-access-token)
```

You'll need to add the header `Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}` (replacing `${TOKEN}` with the value).

**BUT** Please use a client library.