# GCP - background/design of having gcloud credentials and default application credentials

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-platform

GCP `gcloud` command has its access credential for each user account.

[gcloud auth login](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/login)

> Obtains **access credentials for your user account** via a web-based authorization flow. When this command completes successfully, it sets the active account in the current configuration to the account specified.

GCP SDK has Application Default Credentials (ADC)

[gcloud auth application-default login](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/login)

> Obtains **user access credentials** via a web flow and puts them in the well-known location for Application Default Credentials (ADC).
>
> This command has no effect on the user account(s) set up by the gcloud auth login command.
>
> Any credentials previously generated by gcloud auth application-default login will be overwritten.

Both `gcloud auth login` and `gcloud auth application-default login` open up a web page to select a google account.

Question is why do we need two different ways to get credential for google account? What are the reasons?

## Notes

- [Difference between "gcloud auth application-default login" and "gcloud auth login"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53306131/difference-between-gcloud-auth-application-default-login-and-gcloud-auth-logi)

Answer (score 3):

The key is in this sentence:

> well-known location for Application Default Credentials (ADC)

ADC is a flow used by Google Cloud client libraries, the library expect a file to located in a specific location (depending on the OS) to perform Authentication to GCP API's

You can think about it this way:

- gcloud auth login is to grab credentials for a user to be able to perform gcloud commands
- gcloud auth application-default is to grab credentials for a user to be used by applications developers using client libraries.

Comment: gcloud auth application-default is also used for third party application, such as Terraform

Comment: ADC is a method of searching for credentials in known locations (File, Environment, Metadata).