# gcloud auth how to check if logged in, in a headless manner?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I am trying to check if one's application credentials are still valid, in a headless manner.

- `gcloud auth application-default print-access-token` will prompt for a password, so it's not headless.
- `gcloud auth login --brief` ends up pulling up a browser, so it's not headless.

Is there some way to check if credentials are still valid, without logging in?

---

To address some comments, I am using a user account. This is what I am seeing:

```
> gcloud auth application-default print-access-token
Reauthentication required.
Please enter your password:
```

The password it is prompting for here is my Google Account password.

Here is my `gcloud info` output:

```
Google Cloud SDK [468.0.0]

Platform: [Mac OS X, arm] uname_result(system='Darwin', node='User-Computer.local', release='23.3.0', version='Darwin Kernel Version 23.3.0: Wed Dec 20 21:30:59 PST 2023; root:xnu-10002.81.5~7/RELEASE_ARM64_T6030', machine='arm64')
Locale: ('en_US', 'UTF-8')
Python Version: [3.12.2 (main, Feb 28 2024, 10:45:25) [Clang 15.0.0 (clang-1500.1.0.2.5)]]
Python Location: [/Users/user/code/repo/venv/bin/python3]
OpenSSL: [OpenSSL 3.2.1 30 Jan 2024]
Requests Version: [2.25.1]
urllib3 Version: [1.26.9]
Default CA certs file: [/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/466.0.0/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/certifi/cacert.pem]
Site Packages: [Enabled]

Installation Root: [/opt/homebrew/share/google-cloud-sdk]
Installed Components:
  gsutil: [5.27]
  core: [2024.03.08]
  bq: [2.0.101]
  gcloud-crc32c: [1.0.0]
System PATH: [/Users/user/code/repo/venv/bin:/Users/user/.pyenv/shims:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin:/Users/user/.local/bin:/Users/user/.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins/diff-so-fancy:/opt/homebrew/opt/fzf/bin]
Python PATH: [/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/466.0.0/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party:/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/466.0.0/google-cloud-sdk/lib:/opt/homebrew/share/google-cloud-sdk/lib:/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.12.2/lib/python312.zip:/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.12.2/lib/python3.12:/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.12.2/lib/python3.12/lib-dynload:/Users/user/code/repo:/Users/user/code/repo/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages]
Cloud SDK on PATH: [False]
Kubectl on PATH: [/usr/local/bin/kubectl]

Installation Properties: [/opt/homebrew/share/google-cloud-sdk/properties]
User Config Directory: [/Users/user/.config/gcloud]
Active Configuration Name: [default]
Active Configuration Path: [/Users/user/.config/gcloud/configurations/config_default]

Account: [email@example.com]
Project: [project]
Universe Domain: [googleapis.com]

Current Properties:
  [core]
    account: [email@example.com] (property file)
    disable_usage_reporting: [true] (property file)
    project: [project] (property file)

Logs Directory: [/Users/user/.config/gcloud/logs]
Last Log File: [/Users/user/.config/gcloud/logs/2024.03.13/09.22.57.790126.log]

git: [git version 2.44.0]
ssh: [OpenSSH_9.4p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6]
```

Comment: Where are you running this command (which service)? `gcloud auth login` is a developer command. Do not use that in production environments. If your application is running on one of the Google compute services, your app should be using the metadata service or an explicitly specified service account.

Comment: I am running this command in a `Makefile` check of my development environment, so it is at development time (not in production)

Comment: If you issue a gcloud CLI command that requires an authenticated user, and the user isn't authenticated, the command will error out. You should catch the error and check if it's due to a user not being authenticated.

Comment: @NoCommandLine for me, `gcloud auth application-default print-access-token` immediately prompts for a password, which is not throwing an error. Is there some way I can get it to throw an error instead?

Comment: Every time I run "gcloud auth application-default print-access-token", it never ask for password and didn't find any documentation about a password so I was unable to replicate your situation. Could you mention how to reproduce it if possible?

Comment: I have a possible fix, though I couldn't verify it since I wasn't able to reproduce the password scenario.
Could you try add `-q`, so the command will be: `gcloud auth application-default print-access-token -q`

Comment: as stated by Walid, `gcloud` never asks for a password when trying to print the auth token. As far as `gcloud` is concerned  you're either logged in, or you're not. Refer to the [relevant docs](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/print-access-token) here. The question then becomes, what is prompting the password? What is the exact prompt you're getting? No paraphrasing here, provide the exact prompt you get as is...

Comment: note that the auth for `gcloud` needs to be done once, but granting it access will provide a refresh token, which `gcloud` uses internally to get the access token. The only thing I can think of is that your admin has set a maximum session duration for the `gcloud` auth (eg [session length](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/authorizing#set-session-length)). You should be able to work around that by using a service account to authenticate instead of a user account. [Details here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/authorizing#service-account)

Comment: Are you using User accounts or Service Accounts to set up the CLI `gcloud`? Access and Refresh tokens generated by user accounts expire. For a headless environment only use a service account to authorize the CLI `gcloud`.

Comment: Hello @JohnHanley and all, I added the password prompt, that I am using a User account and `gcloud info` output to the question. Even though I am using a User account, I would like a headless way of _checking_ if I am authenticated. I have also observed that sometimes `gcloud auth application-default print-access-token` will not prompt for a password, and sometimes it will prompt for a password, which I don't really understand why it's flaky. Happy to ascertain more info if needed

Comment: Which password is required? The one for your macOS username or the Google account?

Comment: @JohnHanley thanks for asking, it's the Google Account password. I have also added this info to the question

Comment: Also @WalidGhallab, running `gcloud auth application-default print-access-token -q` will still prompt for the password. It says `Reauthentication required.\nPlease enter your password:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When talking about GCP, there are two different kinds of authentication:

- authentication for the gcloud CLI
- authentication for other software (e.g. Python programs) running on your computer that needs to access GCP, using gcloud Application Default Credentials (ADC)

You can read about the difference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53306131/difference-between-gcloud-auth-application-default-login-and-gcloud-auth-logi).

### GCloud CLI authentication test

You can try to run a command that should be available to all users, regardless of IAM roles. For example: `gcloud auth print-access-token` or `gcloud projects list`.

In a bash script, you could use it like this:

```bash
if gcloud projects list &> /dev/null; then
    echo "logged"
else
    echo "not logged"
fi
```

I couldn't find it in the documentation, but from reading the gcloud source code it appears that with some configurations or auth methods the CLI might ask for a password prompt to reauthenticate the session.
In that case, you could "defeat" the stdin with the [--quiet](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference#--quiet) parameter or by passing an empty string to it:

```bash
if echo "" | gcloud projects list &> /dev/null; then
    echo "logged"
else
    echo "not logged"
fi
```

### ADC authentication test

your initial attempt was correct, as explained in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/print-access-token) `gcloud auth application-default print-access-token` will print an auth token only if ADC is set up correctly on your machine, with valid credentials.

The password prompt you are experiencing can be disabled in the same way as above, with the [--quiet](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference#--quiet) parameter or by passing an empty string to it.

```bash
if echo "" | gcloud auth application-default print-access-token &> /dev/null; then
    echo "logged"
else
    echo "not logged"
fi
```

Comment: Hello @Robalb, the output of running that command for me is `Please enter your password:`, so that doesn't quite work. How can I defeat `stdin` as well?

Comment: @IntrastellarExplorer Thanks for the descriptive feedback. I couldn't reproduce the behaviour of your gcli installation, however i found the string you provided in the gcloud source code. I've updated the answer with a solution that should work for you, with that said it could be helpful if you provided some info about your gcli installation: A lot of info is printed by `gcloud info`, some informations must be censored though

Comment: Thank you @Robalb. I have tested it, and found that `gcloud projects list` will prompt for a password. Running `gcloud auth login`, then `gcloud projects list` will no longer prompt for a password. So thank you! Do you think you could pose a way to perform a similar check, but for ADC (`gcloud auth application-default login`)? I am interested in ADC part

Comment: @IntrastellarExplorer for testing the ADC auth, the initial command you posted `gcloud auth application-default print-access-token` is the correct solution since it will only print the token if you have ADC set up correctly and with valid credentials. You can suppress the password prompt issue in the same way I described in the answer.

Comment: Sadly @Robalb the `echo "" | gcloud auth application-default print-access-token` is giving a 0 return code, despite not actually being a successful login. So actually the `echo "" |` trick isn't working with `gcloud auth application-default print-access-token`

Comment: Also, specifying `--quiet` does not suppress the password prompt either, fwiw

Comment: I opened https://github.com/twistedpair/google-cloud-sdk/issues/11 about the `echo ""` leading to a zero return code, I think it's a bug. Any other ideas/workarounds here?

Comment: @IntrastellarExplorer you could always use grep or other command line tools to check for specific content in the response, and base your logic on that instead of the return code.