# gsutil cp - AccessDeniedException with a compute engine service account

Tags: mongodb, google-compute-engine

Using Google Cloud Launcher we've deployed a Mongodb replicaset.

We are know configuring backups being uploaded to buckets.

Under the VM Cloud API access scopes, [with the machine stoped](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances#changeserviceaccountandscopes), we've given Full access to Storage

When we try to upload using `gsutil cp`, we get the following error:

```
Copying file://whateverfilewe try [Content-Type=application/octet-stream]...
AccessDeniedException: 403 Insufficient OAuth2 scope to perform this operation. 
Acceptable scopes: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform
```

Reading documentation, that [scope seems](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/api/how-tos/authorization) way too much.

How should we proceed in order to give access to to a bash script (using the machines assigned service account) within a Compute engine instance upload access to a bucket inside the same project? Is full access really necessary?

Comment: Questions on **professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/about).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems gsutil was caching credentials. This comment gave me the solution:

[gsutil copy returning "AccessDeniedException: 403 Insufficient Permission" from GCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27275063/gsutil-copy-returning-accessdeniedexception-403-insufficient-permission-from#comment69734633_27298944)