# Setting up and using GCP provided pub-sub-to-big-query DataFlow template

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to stream pub/sub messages into a BigQuery table with matching schema. I want to use GCP provided PubSubToBigQuery template to do this, but am unable to set it up successfully.

Here is what I have tried so far

1. I created a GCE instance with permissions to write to GS ([useful link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27275063/gsutil-copy-returning-accessdeniedexception-403-insufficient-permission-from))
2. Clone GCP source from [git](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates) `git clone https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates`
3. As specified [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/templates/PubSubToBigQuery.java), ran:
   `mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.google.cloud.teleport.templates.PubSubToBigQuery...`
4. The process created all the jar files created in the `/staging` buckets. It was supposed to generate template information in `/templates` bucket, but did not.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to execute this command in the project root:

```
#!/bin/bash
PROJECT_ID=XXX
BUCKET_NAME=XXX
PIPELINE_FOLDER=gs://YYY/dataflow/pipelines/pubsub-to-bigquery

# Set the runner
RUNNER=DataflowRunner

# Build the template
mvn compile exec:java \
-Dexec.mainClass=com.google.cloud.teleport.templates.PubSubToBigQuery \
-Dexec.cleanupDaemonThreads=false \
-Dexec.args=" \
--project=${PROJECT_ID} \
--stagingLocation=${PIPELINE_FOLDER}/staging \
--tempLocation=${PIPELINE_FOLDER}/temp \
--templateLocation=${PIPELINE_FOLDER}/template \
--runner=${RUNNER}"
```

And it successfully generated a template file:

```
$gsutil ls -lh gs://YYY/dataflow/pipelines/pubsub-to-bigquery/template
228.33 KiB  2019-01-14T05:54:01Z  gs://YYY/dataflow/pipelines/pubsub-to-bigquery/template
TOTAL: 1 objects, 233805 bytes (228.33 KiB)
```

Could you please paste some logs on your side?