# easiest way to copy data from a VM instance in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine, backup

I have a VM with 60GB and 45GB is used. It has multiple users.

I have deleted old users and now I have about 40GB used. I want to download all the data to my machine. How do I do that? The only way I know is with `scp` the command is something like this one: `gcloud compute scp --recurse <$USER>@<INSTANCE>:/home/$USER ~/$LOCAL_DIR` but it's very slow and might even take a couple of days. Is there a better and easier way to download the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bottleneck here seems to be that you're trying to download a considerable amount of data over SSH which is quite slow.

One thing you can try to speed up the process is break down the download into two parts:

- Upload the content of your VM to Cloud Storage Bucket
- Download the content from Cloud Storage to your machine

So in that case, from the VM you'll execute:

```
gsutil cp -R /home/$USER gs://BUCKET_NAME
```

And then from your local machine:

```
gsutil cp -R gs://BUCKET_NAME ~/$LOCAL_DIR
```

Gsutil uses [parallel composite uploads](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp#parallel-composite-uploads) to speed up uploading large files, in case you have any. And in the first step you'll be doing GCP <-> GCP communication which will be faster than downloading from SSH directly.

Comment: I am getting `CommandException: No URLs matched: <$USER>@<INSTANCE>:/$HOME`

Comment: what was the exact command you tried to run? I have edited my answer because I realised I mistakenly copied the SSH part of the command, so `<$USER>@<INSTANCE>:` should be removed

Comment: I created a storage bucket named it apple-usa-backup and I tried the command `gsutils cp -R darkdead@apple-usa:/home gs://apple-usa-backup` I am getting `CommandException: No URLs matched: darkdead@apple-usa:/home`

Comment: okay yes, the command looks ok but the SSH part should be removed: `gsutils cp -R /home gs://apple-usa-backup`, as you're already inside the VM

Comment: I was not doing this from inside the VM though. I tried by going inside the VM and running `gsutil cp -R /home gs://apple-usa-backup` and I got the error: `Copying file://./darkdead/.bashrc [Content-Type=application/octet-stream]...
AccessDeniedException: 403 Access denied.` I tried using sudo or as a root as well but that didn't work either. Getting same 403 error

Comment: Thank you! I managed to fix it. It was due to permissions errors. [This really helped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27275063/gsutil-copy-returning-accessdeniedexception-403-insufficient-permission-from)

Comment: Happy to see you making it work! Hopefully this helps making the process of retrieving this data faster

Comment: Honestly, it doesn't look like it does. So far it has only transferred about 700MB. But since I am running it in the VM I decided to install tmux and run the command inside that. I can just let it run in the background and not worry about it so that's great

Comment: 13.3GB done so far. Another couple of days before everything gets transferred.