# find out principal for 403 access denied

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-iam

I try copying a file to Google Cloud Storage using the command

```
gsutil cp access.log gs://XXX
```

and I get

```
Copying file://access.log [Content-Type=application/octet-stream]...
AccessDeniedException: 403 Access denied.
```

I would like to know who is the principle who got "access denied". Was it my OS user or the compute engine service account? How can I find this out? The Log Explorer does not seem to know of an "access denied".

Comment: If it was the OS user, wouldn't the error like: `sh gsutil permission denied`? I think it's related to the scopes of your compute engine account. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27275063/gsutil-copy-returning-accessdeniedexception-403-insufficient-permission-from) answer.

Comment: Where are you running this command?

Comment: It depends on what you configured. For Compute Engine, you have the configured service account for the instance. That service accounts needs the IAM role granting access to Cloud Storage. However, if you configured the SDK, which gsutil is part of, then check with `gcloud auth list`. Note: `gsutil` also supports its own credentials. The CLI credentials have preference over the assigned service account (metadata credentials). Edit your post with details.

Comment: There is one more item to check. What are the VM's `Access Scopes`? Those can limit IAM permissions. The default scope is read-only. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts#accesscopesiam

Comment: Read this link to understand how Application Default Credentials (ADC) work: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/application-default-credentials

Comment: Feel free to update the status of the question. Let me know the answer below helps to resolve your issue? I am happy to help you if you have any further queries.

Comment: Veera, many thanks. Indeed, I think I recall the solution was setting "Cloud Storage" to "read/write" in the VM's access scope. It did help, however, my question is rather - why is this not in the logs?

Comment: Enable Audit logs that record access scopes within your Google Cloud resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per GCP Official doc on [Limit service account privileges](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/best-practices-service-accounts#access-scopes);

> **Service accounts are principals and can be granted access to a resource like a regular user account. However, service accounts often
> have greater access to more resources than a typical user.**

By default your machine should have **READ access** to the buckets in the same project, but configuration is required before you can write to them.

**Set proper Access scopes to resolve the error `AccessDeniedException: 403 Access denied` as per the below steps:**

1. Navigate to [console.cloud.google.com](http://console.cloud.google.com) >> select your project from the drop down menu >> select your VM and click STOP in the top menu bar.
2. Once your VM has been stopped, click on its name and then EDIT in the top menu bar.
3. Scroll down until you see a header called Access Scopes, which will likely be on the Allow default access selection.
4. Select Set access for each API as your option, then scroll down until you see Storage, which is likely set on READ: **change it to READ/WRITE**, or whatever you feel is necessary for your use case.
5. Save your changes and restart your VM.

Refer to [Changing the service account and access scopes for an instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances#changeserviceaccountandscopes) for more information.